# Inserting a linebreak after 5 comma separated values

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I'm trying to covert a list like so:

```
name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name
```

to

```
name,name,name,name,name
name,name,name,name,name
name,name
```

How would I do this using bash line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name,name' | sed 's/\([^,]*\(,[^,]*\)\{4\}\),/\1\n/g'
name,name,name,name,name
name,name,name,name,name
name,name
```

`[^,]*` matches any character but not of a `,` zero or more times. In basic sed, capturing groups are denoted by `\(...\)`